# Md-tab extremely slow when using ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, tabs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid, angular-material

I have 5 [tabs of angular material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.tabs) and my heaviest tab consist of 1 [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/). If i initialize it with 1000 rows and 50 columns (which should be okay according to their demos), changing the tab from one to another became extremely slow (8-18 second for "non-grid tabs" and 22-crash seconds for "grid tab"). It is slow even if i disable the animation between tabpanel transitions.

Is there any solution to speed up the tabs (or grid)?

Comment: can you supply some code to examine ?
use profiler in dev tools to check which function call takes maximum time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found!

Assigning a very small number to the attribute "exceesRows" is the only way to speed up the ui-grid (and that really helps). Using this, you actually restrict the number of rows to be loaded for each user view. And now i see the slowness has nothing to do with the md-tab.